# Audio error on autoplay, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to autoplay audio after getting new message from websocket, but i've this this error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

I made a sample of my case, reload the page and dont interact with the page for 5 second the error message will shown up
     https://codepen.io/rey32120023/pen/bGEavYW

i know why this happen, but i dont know to fix this

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: I get no error messages, the audio works

Comment: Did u interact with page after reload the page? Something like scrolling or click or press something,  i set 5 sec timout before triggering the sound, the error should be shown up if you dont interact with the page

Comment: No interactions, no. Which browser are you using?

Comment: i use google chrome